# Creating dynamic associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create an associative array in javascript that has a specific structure.

```
winning = [Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3], Array[3]]
0: Array[3]
   1: 0
   2: 0
   3: 0

1: Array[3]
   4: 0
   5: 0
   6: 0

2: Array[3]
3: Array[3]
4: Array[3]
5: Array[3]
6: Array[3]
7: Array[3]
```

I am looking for something similar to above. The index always starts at zero inside the nested arrays. I want control over the index number and also I need to be able to update the specific index value dynamically so that I can change it to a 1 or a -1. My current array created like this:

```
var winning = [[1,2,3],[4,5,6],[7,8,9],
              [1,4,7],[2,5,8],[3,6,9],
              [1,5,9],[7,5,3]];
```

I believe I should be able to update the values using something like this

```
winning[1][5] = -1;
```

which should update

```
1: Array[3]
   4: 0
   5: -1
   6: 0
```

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Create the array from what? Yes ..`winning[1][5] = -1;` is proper syntax...but there are no associative arrays in javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array is denoted by square `[]` brackets whereas an associative array (also known as an Object) is denoted by curly `{}` brackets.

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/4jLeC/)

```
var winning = [{1:0,2:0,3:0},{4:0,5:0,6:0},{7:0,8:0,9:0},
               {1:0,4:0,7:0},{2:0,5:0,8:0},{3:0,6:0,9:0},
               {1:0,5:0,9:0},{7:0,5:0,3:0}];

winning[1][5] = -1;

console.log( winning );
```